# Ignoring the first column of the kmeans cluster input data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cluster-analysis, k-means

**INPUT DATA**
**(key,datapoints)**

A,1,2,0,1,2,1,2,1
B,2,2,3,1,1,1,1,0
C,3,1,2,3,4,5,0,1
D,1,2,0,1,2,5,0,1
....

I have the input data in the above format. I want to perform Kmeans cluserting of the above data ignoring the first column and would like to identify which centre each of the record belongs to. I have discarded the first col (key) and able to find the cluster centres using below code, but I'm expecting the output in below format
(key,cluster_centre)
A,0
B,2
C,1
D,0
...

Code:

```
data = sc.textFile("/home/user/inputfile.txt")
parsedData = data.map(lambda line: array([long(x.strip()) for x in line.split(',')]))
model = KMeans.train(parsedData, 3, maxIterations=10, runs=10, initializationMode="random")
centers = model.clusterCenters
for center in centers: print(center)
```

Comment: What is the problem? I do not understand.

Comment: Use array subset `[1:]` to remove the first column?

Answer (score -1):

filtered_cols = parsed_data.map(lambda x: x[1]) 
model = KMeans.train(filtered_cols, 3, maxIterations=10, runs=10, initializationMode="random")
centers = model.clusterCenters 
for center in centers: print(center)